# visual c++ force the release build use the debug build code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, ocr

i am using an open source project on work for an internal application.
It is the cuneiform linux ocr engine.
When i build this in debug mode, the build works perfectly.
The release build hangs on some images without any feedback.

Is it possible to change the compiler flags, that the release build uses the debug build code?
I have tried to edit the ifdef and ifndef configurations in the code without success.

I am a c# developer with only basic skills in c++.

The main fact i want to use the release build is that the server where it is installed should only use the msvc++ runtime. the debug dll's are only delivered by a visual studio installation.

regards
Ingo

Comment: Just check your code thoroughly there may be something left while compiling for release version which may be enabled for debug build.

Answer (score 1):

This is unadvisable. In this situation (Debug running fine, Release not running), it tends to fall down to uninitialized variables somewhere. Its good practice to place assertions throughout your code which work as a sanity check for developers (asserts are usually not compiled as part of a Release build, but they are part of a Debug build) to check for conditions like this.

A Debug build will have lots of extra symbol information as well as more stringent assigning of values in your code to ensure a debugger can hook into it. This sometimes mitigates issues like this since the compiler will correctly initialize variables for a debugger, variables which if not initialized correctly produce undefined behavior (sometimes this undefined behavior is quite fatal for a programs execution!). Hence, a Release build not working when Debug one does.

Comment: In addition, the license terms of Visual Studio only allow you to freely redistribute the "release" version of the libraries -- you _can_ use the debug libraries, but only for debugging the application.

Comment: @TripeHound That is the fact that i don't want to use the debug build!

Comment: @Ifgtm Thanks for that tip! I know there are some warnings for not initialized variables... I will check it up